# Distance using disparity map(opencv)

Tags: c++, opencv

I am working on a project in OpenCV(c++).Basically my aim is to estimate the real-world distance through disparity map.
Now I have already calculated disparity ( max disparity--as my object of interest is the one nearest to the camera ),so now how do I go about calculating the distance.The value of disparity that I got is 1264 and my focal length is around 28 mm.
Using the formula D=b*f/d { b=60 mm,f=28 mm,d=1264 pixels } 
'D' comes out to be 1.38 units,whereas my actual distance is 150 cm.The numerical value regardless the units is wrong! :/ .
Where exactly am I going wrong?
Any help is appreciated.

The code that I wrote :
( C++ & Opencv 3.1 )

```
#include<iostream>

#include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace std;

using namespace cv;


int main() {

Mat left, right, dis;

float b = 6, f = 2.8, d, pd = 104;
left = imread("leftm.jpg", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

right = imread("rightm.jpg", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
imshow("or", right);

blur(left, left, Size(5, 5), Point(-1, -1));
blur(right, right, Size(5, 5), Point(-1, -1));


Ptr<StereoBM> sbm = StereoBM::create(16 * 5, 21);

sbm->compute(left, right, dis);
double min, max;
erode(dis, dis, Mat(), Point(-1, -1), 3);

//dilate(dis, dis, Mat(), Point(-1, -1), 1);

minMaxLoc(dis, &min, &max);
dis.convertTo(dis, CV_8UC1, .45);



imshow("disparity", dis);
cout << "disparity beaches!!!!"<<endl;
cout << "max disparity :" << max << endl;
d = max;
cout << " => distance = " << (((b*f) / d)*pd)*100<<" cm"<<endl;
waitKey(0);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: D has the unit mm^2/pixel, so you have to express your disparity in mm. Try to transform your disparity mit with [cv::reprojectImageTo3D](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#reprojectimageto3d) with the matrix Q from e.g `stereoRectify`.

Comment: The units are not the concern here,as I mentioned the numerical part( regardless the units ) is incorrect@PSchn